# Playing fullscreen video on OS X with AVPlayer

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avplayer

I would like to know what's the best way to play a video in bundle on Mac full screen using AVPlayer.

I tried this and it works only if I create a new scene/ViewController, attached a AVPlayerView, and then in viewDidLoad to load the file.

```
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wallaby", ofType:"m4v"))
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    playerView.player = videoPlayer
    videoPlayer.play()
```

The problems:

- this method does not go full screen
- I see no button to go full screen

The best I can do is to present a full screen window:

```
self.view.frame.size = NSScreen.mainScreen().frame.size
```

Thanks for any tips or pointers to some sample codes!

Answer (score 2):

`AVPlayerView` class includes the `showsFullScreenToggleButton` property.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this on latest Yosemite, once you click on the full screen toggle button and go into full screen, the screen can no longer be operated (click on anywhere only result in a beep). The only way to get out of the app is to Command-Q.

Comment: Don't you see the "back to normal size" button in the controls bar?

Comment: Once I play in full screen, the toggle button (in fact the whole screen) is not clickable, like they are no longer the front most window. I am using Yosemite and not sure what have I done wrong (do I need to make the window front most or anything)?

Comment: Send me you xcode project if you want, I'll try it on Mavericks

Comment: Thanks Michele for the suggestion. I am developing the app for Yosemite, so whether it works on Mavericks or not is not important.

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing this issue with AVPlayerView also. If I enable the fullscreen button like this:

```
self.playerView.showsFullScreenToggleButton = YES;
```

And I click on the fullscreen button the video goes to fullscreen, however, the app does not take any key inputs and you can't activate Mission Montrol, LaunchPad, etc. This is a very bad user experience and I believe that if you submit an application like this to the Mac App Store it will get rejected. Also I've tried to make my AVPlayerView to become the first responder but it to no avail.

### Solution

So, I looked at how QuickTime Player works in relation to bringing a video in fullscreen. And I noticed that it does not have a button for fullscreen on the player controls. The way it handles fullscreen is by when the user clicks the window's fullscreen control it readjusts the size of the, if I am correct the AVPlayerView or whatever Apple is using. To implement something similar to this do the following:

```
//The window that contains your AVPlayerView set the delegate
 [self.window setDelegate:self];


//So you can respond to these notifications

- (void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification{
        // wait a bit
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if (self.playerView.isReadyForDisplay == YES) {

        //Make sure the playerView is ready for display

        //Set the playerView to the screen's current frame (Very Important!)
         [self.playerView setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]];

        //Do other UI related things here e.g hide elements e.t.c

        }

        });
        }

- (void)windowWillExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification{
//Do other UI related things here e.g show elements e.t.c

}

//If you have a ToolBar in your application do this:

- (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)window:(NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:(NSApplicationPresentationOptions)proposedOptions
{
    return (NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen |
            NSApplicationPresentationHideDock |
            NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar |
            NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideToolbar);
}

// To determine if the window is in fullscreen e.g. if the application opened/restored in a fullscreen state the windowDidEnterFullScreen will not be called. So you need to do this:

- (BOOL) isFullScreenMode {
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions opts = [[NSApplication sharedApplication ] presentationOptions];
    if ( opts & NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

#### Conclusion

I hoped that this answered your question. Also, I think this is a bug on Apple's part, so I will file a bug report tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I found that why the toggle button in fullscreen mode is not clickable, because you probebly show a view instead of window for example you use storyboard segue between a button and a view, you should link the button to a window(the view's parent).

Answer (score -1):

In **Swift**:

```
   import UIKit
    import AVKit
    import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        // Use a local or remote URL
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)!

        // Make an AVPlayer
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",
                                                         name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
                                                         object: avPlayer.currentItem)
        avPlayer.play()

        // Make the AVPlayerLayer and add it to self.view's layer
        let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

        /*
        @abstract       A string defining how the video is displayed within an AVPlayerLayer bounds rect.
        @discusssion    Options are AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect, AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        and AVLayerVideoGravityResize. AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect is default.
        See <AVFoundation/AVAnimation.h> for a description of these options.
        */
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        avPlayerLayer.zPosition = -1

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
        }

        func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
            let avPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
            avPlayerItem.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
        }

    }
```

Comment: The OP asked for OS X, this code will only work on iOS (imports UIKit).